# How to do an auto update query to mysql databases table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to know how to do an autoupdate to any table.
For example table `is_approved` it's always set to `0` and I would like to do it `1`.

Comment: Is ambiguous, what do you mean? You wan to set a default value for a column or ?

Comment: What will trigger the autoupdate? How does the system "know" if it should become `0` or `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want every record to be updated just execute an update query without a where statement in it. If you mean you want it to be automatically triggert at some point in time you must look into cronjobs or something like that.

To do each record do: `UPDATE`mytable`SET`is_approved`=1`

Comment: ya i wan to do with every record , but how do i do it ?

Comment: if i want to do each time automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, however

if you want to autoupdate based on a condition use mysql triggers. have it fire on update, perform a check on the value and then perform an action http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html for more information.

If you want it to place 1 in the datebase instead of 0 as the default, you need to set that as the default value when creating the database, or update the database with that default value.

Comment: if i want to do each time automatically ?